AI and the concept of needs
Could large language models (LLM / "AI") be improved (made more human-like in their behaviour) by adding virtual needs?
Is it right to assume, that social interaction has evolved by learning that one can sustain their needs more easily if theye persuade others to cooperate?
How would a LLM change, if we were to introduce a mechanic that indicates a sub-optimal status for to the machine that needs external interference in order to be improved?
LLMs have no way of interfering with the environment/hardware it is executed on, and thus has no understanding or indeed need for self preservation and/or the concept of mortality.
Bottomline: is pain essential to human behaviour and is there a way to teach it to AI?

Sounds like a question for an AI site, not a philosophy one. But there's a lot going on with AI, and every additional variable increases complexity, which makes the model harder to train sufficiently, and what you're proposing probably doesn't really serve the use case nor design and training process of LLMs. The evolution question should probably go on a biology site or something. But that is vaguely correct, although for natural selection, it doesn't (directly) matter whether you've learnt to do something easily, it matters whether you live or die (although there's certainly a link there).

LLMs are only designed to predict the next word of a string of words in a given context. They do not interact socially with the user, although they sure look like they do. When training an AI pain is represented as a negative feedback. We can teach an AI to play a RPG by giving it a negative feedback when it walks on a trap or something. But this has more to do with Markov chains and other puzzle solving methods than LLMs.

Depends on what you mean by 'virtual need'. What you are noticing is that cognition is embodied: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/

I’m voting to close this question because it's exploratory and speculative. The site aspires to a fact-based Q&A format. You should post this over at https://thephilosophyforum.com/
